# Google Tag Manager - Analytics per domain

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have searched the web - but I see there are so many outdated and not so well covered.

My client is having a site - that runs in Wordpress with WPML for multilingual content. That is not so important for this question - I guess, but:

There are three top level domains, one for each language.

```
domain.se
domain.no
domain.dk
```

These sites has the same code - and the same Google Tag Manager code installed. Is that ok? We do want to have a separate Google Analytics account for each language (domain)

Is one GTM account enough for this, but still having this one and only GTM add the right GA-script on each of the domains?

We have been told so - that it is a good way, but - we have set up a container for each domain in GTM, but still no go

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like the data from each of the domains to be aggregated together and appear in the same Google Analytics property, you will want to set up [cross domain tracking](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106951).

If you want to be able to separate the data by domain, I would set up individual containers in GTM that point to individual properties in GA.

Comment: Okey, but if I do individual containers, then I will need to make 3 containers (DK, NO, SE). No problem

BUT – Do I in wordpress/php check for current domain, and then add in the 3 containers in the CMS. Or can Google Tag Manager itself figure this out from itself?

Comment: Each GTM container will have a unique container ID.  The tracking code that you place in the head section of your site contains the GTM container ID so it will be up to you to set the correct container id on each of the domains.